# CRM Dynamics 4.0 user is missing "Run Workflow..." button

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have ONE user in my entire company that does not have the "Run Workflow..." button where everyone else does.  I've checked the roles she is in, and she has no less than four different roles that have the run workflow privelege.

Has anyone run into this before? I'm desperate to get this working for her, and Google searches have failed me.

I realize it's not really a development question, but it doesn't really fit on ServerFault either.

**Update:**

Well, in my defense, I didn't set up these roles, so I claim ignorance. Also, the color-coded pie circles could be better done.

We added her to one more role, that was more priveleges, and that worked.

So I compared the roles that worked and didn't work, and it turns out she only had User level access to ***read*** workflows. She needed Business Unit level.  The difference between yellow 1/4 pie and yellow 1/2 pie.

I don't like those symbols much.

I'm going to give the answer to PolshGiant, because he was the closest to the answer, given that I ran everyone off in the wrong direction..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the scope of the workflow? If it's set to something lower than Organization, she may not be be able to see it due to her business unit.

Some other quick things to try that might help move your troubleshooting along:

- If she creates an On Demand workflow for herself, does the button appear?
- Can you temporarily raise her privileges just to see if the button appears?
- You could try enabling tracing on the server.  Turn tracing on, have her load the page, and then turn tracing off. It's possible you could find something helpful in the trace output. If you're using the Trace Log Viewer and don't see any errors or warnings, there might still be some helpful information at the Info or Verbose levels.
- Since elevating her privileges isn't really an option, do you have a test user available to you or can you create one? You could set it up to have exactly the same roles she has.  If the test user also doesn't see the button, that would point towards a privilege issue. And then you could then also raise the privs of the test account to see if that solves the problem.

  - Another way of accomplishing the above would be to temporarily reduce the roles of a user that can see the button to match the roles that she has to see if the button then disappears.

Comment: All of our workflows are Organization Level, and she's in the same organization *and* business unit as everyone else. We only have the one Organization in our instance, and only a couple of business units. Another good call though. I will try the On Demand workflow, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: The raising priveleges gives me the heebie-jeebies, only because of the user that the issue is with. I Really don't want to give her any more priveleges than she needs.

Comment: @Moose: Not sure if SO sends you updates when an answer gets edited, so I'm dropping a quick line here since I think comments generate alert emails. (I checked the FAQ and meta sites but couldn't find the info about when alert emails get sent out.)

Comment: Thanks, Polshgiant, I actually have users with priveleges *less* than she has, and they still see the button.  The whole problem is that I can't reproduce it with any user except her.  It's not the machine because she is currently on a temporary machine. I need to do a lot more testing to try to separate her id from the machine, but I haven't had time to get to it. Currently it's not high on the priority list. :-/

Answer (score 2):

Is the window expanded? I know I've seen previous claims of buttons disappearing in CRM, only to find that the width of the window was small enough that CRM started collapsing buttons.

Comment: Good call, have seen that happen too.

Comment: Good call, but sadly no, I checked that too.  Plenty of room.

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark:  Is the CAL Access Mode for the user set to `Full`?  If it's set to `Read-Only` the user won't have access to the `Run Workflow...` button.